# Plugin development- Mac version of MS-Office

Tags: macos

I want to create a plugin for MS Office, in mac.

I do not know, how to start.
I googled, havnt found anything.I just need to know, how the plugin development starts?
What are the things required?
What do i need to create a plugin?

all this for mac version of MS-Office

This is the last place, i am looking out for some help.

Thanks